# Forking a child process that does not use it´s own memory copy

Tags: c, memory, fork, ipc

What i want to achieve is the following:
Spawn a new childprocess (pchild) that DOES NOT use its own, but the memoryblock from its parentprocess (pparent).

Why i want to achieve this behavior:
Think of multiple tests where the first one leads to segvault.
Normally your process would stop here due to segfault, all the other tests wouldn't be executed anymore. Therefore i want to encapsule each test in its own process.

Main Problem: 
Once i spawn a process it gets its own memory copy (well, i'm 
aware of the fact that this is not totally true for all OS, due to 'copy on write' technique). Think of e.g. testing tree functionallity where i have a node structure that has two pointers to other nodes. Once i retrieve a node by e.g. using a pipe or some shared memory block those pointers point to an address which is part of the memory block of the pchild and therefore i get a segvault when i try from pparent to get the childnode by following the pointers inside the node structure.

A Thread isn´t usefull, due to the main behavior some OS have once a segfault happens. (Killing child and father due to 'unclear state' ).

What i have so far (only fork testing part):

```
int main (void) {
    // forking
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0 ) {
        // somewhat went wrong
        printf("An error occured!");
    } else if (pid != 0) {                              // inside parent
        // closing writing end, as not needed
        if(wait(NULL)!=0){
            printf("Segfault in Child\n");
        } else {
            printf("Everyone is done!\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("Child forked");
        char *s = (char *)0xDEADBEEF;
        *s = 'a';
        printf("this probally is never executed due to segfault\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now my idea is to try to let the pchild access the memory segment of pparent only.
I'd welcome any ideas on how to do so.
Greetings,
Lars

Comment: Are you sure you need this? If one test crashes, what's the point in running further tests?

Comment: If you're on Linux, you might be able to actually do this insane scheme by way of `clone()`.

Comment: fork_and_exec gdb and attach it to the main process.

Comment: Actually, I really don't see the point why testing *on an exact copy of the parent's memory* differs so much from "testing on the parent's memory"

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear, but I think you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

My understanding is that you want to run a series of tests, where each test sees the results of previous tests that succeeded, but not tests that crashed/failed. If this is the case, one approach would be:

1. `fork` before each test
2. Execute the test in the child.
3. If the test succeeded, have the parent exit or simply wait while *the child* forks again and executes the next test in its child. If the test failed, have the parent fork again to do the next test.

Another approach might be to keep *your data structures only* in shared memory allocated by `mmap` with `MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANON`, but then if one test left them in an inconsistent state, all future test results would be junk.

Your idea of sharing all memory between processes is technically possible, but it will immediately blow up because they clobber each other's state.

Comment: Well, this answer isn´t that helpful. first of all step 1 & 2 are the thing i want to do. whats the problem with it, is getting back a nice returnvalue. As parent and child have seperate memory, returning a struct which includes pointers (and was allocated in child) from child to parent messes up everything. Because those pointers lead to chield mem, once i follow them when im in parent i get a segfault...

Comment: Most of the test don't build up on each other! - Forgot to say that, sorry!

Comment: @LarsPrehn: If all you want is to return results from the child to the parent, send them over a pipe or use a shared mmap. That's why I said you have an XY problem - you're asking how to do an awful complex hack to achieve something that's easy with standard tools that have well-defined behavior.

Comment: As allready mentioned in the question above: retuning structs via shared memory or using pipes lets me transfer the struct, BUT the pointers inside them point to space from child (because they are allocated in child) so if i get them back in parent and want to access the pointers i try to reach a memory place that's not inside my parent mem block... therefore i get a segfault.

Comment: @LarsPrehn: Yes. To use a pipe you need to serialize the data and deserialize it on on the receiving end. If you're using shared memory you can just put everything (also the pointed-to data) inside the shared memory allocation.

Comment: Okay, so the major key is to allocate enough shared mem space ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Every process has it's own `virtual memory` adress space so there is no way to give a RAM adress to another process (well you can send a number, but in another `virtual memory` address space it will point to different 'real' place).

All you need is another thread. Threads of same process share one `virtual memory` space.

Comment: "Every process has it's own virtual memory adress space so there is no way to give a RAM adress to another process" - definitively not true! See mmap ... "All you need is another thread. Threads of same process share one virtual memory space." ... As i stated out in my question threads aren't helpfull at all. If i wouldn't have known that allready, how could i set up this question?

Answer (score -1):

try to use vfork(); instead of fork();systemcall.
that shares the Resources of parent and child process.

Comment: Given that the only permissible action the child may perform after `vfork()` is to `_exit()` or `exec()`, it's not immediately obvious how it would help the OP.